# How to get Powershell to add types from an assembly it just loaded

Tags: types, .net-assembly, powershell-5.0

I loaded an assembly using Add-Type:

```
 $Typename = '\\crtwfaadvlkv0.d2dbfg.com\PRODUCTION\Vision\Apps\VisionPipeline\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll'
 Add-Type -LiteralPath $TypeName
```

and confirmed it was loaded

```
> [appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() |
>> Sort-Object -Property FullName |
>> Select-Object -Property FullName;

(partial results)

Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342
```

Next I want to load the classes defined in the assembly so I can use them, but this errors out:

```
> $oracletpe = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' -PassThru
Add-Type : Cannot add type. The assembly 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' could not be found.
At line:1 char:14
+ ... oracletpe = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' -PassTh ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess:String) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_NOT_FOUND,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. One or more required assemblies are missing.
At line:1 char:14
+ ... oracletpe = Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess' -PassTh ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ASSEMBLY_LOAD_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```

So, it looks like PowerShell can't find the assembly it just loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to load the assembly twice (first by Path, second by Name)?

Just add the "-PassThru" Parameter to the first Add-Type command (with the LiteralPath) and assign the result to a variable.

Comment: I don't want to load it twice.  I think I'm not getting how this operates.  I'm trying to load the dll then in the second call, load the types into the namespace.  I'm mystified that Posh cannot find the assembly, since it just loaded it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add it twice, then you don't need the second loading.

As mentioned in my comment, just add the "-PassThru" parameter to the first "Add-Type" command.

```
$assemblyFilePath = '\\crtwfaadvlkv0.d2dbfg.com\PRODUCTION\Vision\Apps\VisionPipeline\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll'
$assembly = Add-Type -LiteralPath $assemblyFilePath -PassThru

$assembly
```

But if you want to reload it, use the assembly qualified name:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' -PassThru
```

Partial Names are, in general, only allowed for assemblies in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and Assemblies in the application folder (recursive). (but there are some special extensions for that like "host assembly store" for SQL Server and others).

But don't confuse the "application folder" with the folder your script is located in. It's the PowerShell Application Folder: `%WinDir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`
If you want to test it, just place the DLL in that folder and start a new powershell console.

More information about assembly loading (especially with partial name): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading#avoid-binding-on-partial-assembly-names

Answer (score 0):

This was helpful, thanks... I was using this to reference a NuGet Package containing Icons for a WPF form I am populating. Nice to know I can keep my Backend Powershell.

All I ended up doing to get mine to work was put the path to the Added NuGet Reference within the VS Solution inside a variable, and then call it after WPF object Function was called.

```
$assemblyFilePath = "$ScriptRoot\QATool\packages\FontAwesome.Sharp.6.1.1\lib\net40\FontAwesome.Sharp.dll"
```

Then below the Function and the call that combines all the WPF Elements into one Object... I added this line...

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath $assemblyFilePath -PassThru
```